# BeautifulSoup return me an empty object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap some URL with BeautifulSoup. The URL I'm scraping are coming from a google analytics API call, some of then aren't working properly so I need to find a way to skip them.

Here is my initial script which is working properly when I don't have any wrong url :

```
rawdata = []
urllist = []
sharelist = []
mystring = 'http://www.blablabla.com'
def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.

  if results:
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      rawdata.append(row[0])
  else:
    print 'No results found'

  urllist = [mystring + x for x in rawdata]

  for row in urllist:  
            # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

                # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    share = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append((row,share))

  print(sharelist)
```

Following an answer from stack, I had these line to deal with the wrong url :

```
if name_box is None:
  continue
```

Then I had this line :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

At the top of my script to deal with this error `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)`

but now my script return me an empty object.

Here is my final script :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
{...my api call here...}
rawdata = []
urllist = []
sharelist = []
mystring = 'http://www.blablabla.com'
def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.

  if results:
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      rawdata.append(row[0])
  else:
    print 'No results found'

  urllist = [mystring + x for x in rawdata]

  for row in urllist:  
            # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(row)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

                # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    if name_box is None:
      continue
    share = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append((row,share))

  print(sharelist)
```

Comment: Where did  you see the `reload(sys)` logic?

Comment: nowhere :) just taking it from some solutions I found on other questions.

Comment: Anyone or anything that advises you do that should be avoided like the plague! What OS and what application on your OS are you using to run the code? Also which line exactly causes the error, the print?

Comment: I'm on OS X el capitan running the code from my terminal

Comment: You should not use `sys` to change the encoding like that. It's a bad idea. To deal with encoding problems, you should use string encoding methods. IE `print(str(something).encode('utf-8'))` Or pipe the data to a file, instead.

Comment: so you say that it's better so send my url list into a csv for example then dealing with it with the second part of my code ?

Comment: If you remove the reload(sys) what line causes your error? `mystring + x` or the print?

Comment: The encoding problem happens when you try to print the data. However, you can probably write that information to a file without any problems.

Comment: If I only remove the reload(sys) I have this error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'` if I remove all the sys part, I have this error : `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Ok, I'll try to export directly my data into a csv thx !

Comment: I meant all that sys included. Add the full traceback to your question.

Comment: I tried to export my result directly with this `numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", sharelist, delimiter=",")` but got the same error. I think I'll open a new question focus in this issue.

Comment: The issue is all related, add the full traceback and what does `sys.stdout.encoding` output from your shell?

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you. What's `sys.stdout.encoding` ? I already answers you about the error I have no ?

Comment: In your terminal, `import sys;sys.stdout.encoding`, I wanted to see the full traceback to make sure it is the print. Anyway what does the former output? `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126250/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-padraic-cunningham).